# How can an Angular directive have a 'native' parent state when it is compiled elsewhere?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I use `ui-router` to create routes with multiple HTML pages.

I have custom "target" directives within these pages that use `$state.current` in various ways.

But I also have other custom "lookup" directives in other states which load these HTML "templates", find these "target" directives, compile them and insert them into the DOM.

The problem I am having is that when the HTML content is compiled in these second directives, `$state.current` obviously refers to whatever state the application is in when it is compiled, whereas I would like the directive to compile as if it was in its "native" state.

Is there any (easy-ish!) way to get a reference to the target directive's "native" state? i.e. the state connected to the .HTML file which the directive is in? Is there a method (angular, jquery, native js or anything else) to get from the directive to the HTML template file? Then I could do a reverse lookup on the state objects. `element.ownerDocument` can get the URL of the current state, but not the HTML file of the template.

Alternatively, if the second directive had a reference to the "target" state, how should I modify the "target" directive so that it takes a state reference when it is compiled in both scenarios? Something in the compile function perhaps?? - but the docs don't seem to cover this kind of use case... I could do with a pointer in the right direction.

I hope that all makes sense. I have looked around for similar answers, but I guess this is an unusual use case? I'll knock up a Plunker shortly to help illustrate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compile HTML using `$compile`, you pass in a scope object. Instead of using `$state.current` within the directive, could you attach the "state" you need to the scope object that you're passing in?

Comment: Fantastic - thanks @adam - I hadn't realised you could link different $scopes using `$compile`. With my "target" directive which has isolate scope, I had to use `$scope.$parent.targetState` rather than `scope = { targetState: '@' }` but that's probably just me not really getting how `$compile` works yet.

Comment: @StevieP, I see you're new to Stack Overflow. Welcome! If my answer solved you're problem, could you mark it as the accepted answer?